# Selecting the two most common attribute pairings from a Entity-Attribute Table?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a simple Entity-Attribute table in my database describing simply if an Entity has some Attribute by the existance of a row consisting of `(Entity, Attribute)`.

I want to find out, of all the `Entities` with two and only two `Attributes`, what are the most common `Attribute` pairs

For example, if my table looked like:

```
+--------+-----------+
| Entity | Attribute |
+--------+-----------+
| Bob    | A         |
| Sally  | B         |
| Terry  | C         |
| Bob    | B         |
| Sally  | A         |
| Terry  | D         |
| Larry  | C         |
+--------+-----------+
```

I would want it to return

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| Attribute-1 | Attribute-2 | Count |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| A           | B           |     2 |
| C           | D           |     1 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

I currently have a short query that looks like:

```
WITH TwoAtts (
    SELECT entity
    FROM table
    GROUP BY entity
    HAVING COUNT(att) = 2
)
SELECT t1.att, t2.att, COUNT(entity)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.entity = t2.entity
WHERE t1.entity IN (SELECT * FROM TwoAtts)
AND t1.att != t2.att
GROUP BY t1.att, t2.att
ORDER BY COUNT(entity) DESC
```

but is only capable of producing "duplicate" results like

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| Attribute-1 | Attribute-2 | Count |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| A           | B           |     2 |
| B           | A           |     2 |
| D           | C           |     1 |
| C           | D           |     1 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

In a sense I would like to be able to run a unordered DISTINCT / set operator over the two attribute columns, but I am not sure how to acheive this functionality in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you want two levels of aggregation, with some filtering:

```
select attribute_1, attribute_2, count(*)
from (select min(ea.attribute) as attribute_1, max(ea.attribute) as attribute_2
      from entity_attribute ea
      group by entity
      having count(*) = 2
     ) aa
 group by attribute_1, attribute_2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=910dcb1f78234283023d8079ffcd9c01) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: this solution works perfectly, thank you! I didn't know you could use MIN & MAX operators on non-numerical data, especially in this context!